# Newbie - C# For loop, need help stoping loop when i = loopEnd

Tags: c#, loops

I am trying to get my loop to stop when `i` is equal to the `loopEnd` variable. Here is the code:

```
for (int i = loopStart; i < loopEnd; i++)
```

At the moment it stops when `i` is greater than `loopEnd`, but the program won't run if I replace `<` with `=`, and it won't work if I use `==`.

Comment: Is `loopEnd` also an int?  If so, this should stop when `i` is equal to `loopEnd`. Could you show us some more of your code, including the contents of the loop and the part that is indicating to you that `i` is greater than `loopEnd`?

Comment: Is there no way just to have equals as the condition as opposed to equal or greater than?

Comment: If you want it to stop when `i` equals `loopEnd` then the condition should be either `i != loopEnd` or `i < loopEnd`.

Comment: I thought != meant not equal to?

Comment: It does.  You want to loop while the loop variable is not equal to the end condition, so that as soon as it *is* equal your loop stops.

Comment: Okay I get it now.  I thought it was doing it until the condition is met, but it is doing _while_ the condition is met.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

No, currently it will stop when `i` is *equal* to `loopEnd` (because then `i` is *not* less than `loopEnd`). If you *want* it only stop when `i` is greater than `loopEnd`, use `<=` instead:

```
for (int i = loopStart; i <= loopEnd; i++)
```

Note that this approach has problems if `loopEnd` is `int.MaxValue` - you'll loop forever, because when `i` is incremented, it will become `int.MinValue` which is again less than `loopEnd` (unless you're in a checked context, in which case an exception will be thrown).

This may well not be an issue for you, but it's worth being aware of.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = loopStart; i <= loopEnd; i++)
                        //^ apply less or equal operator
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = loopStart; i <= loopEnd; i++)
```

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Use `i != loopEnd`. This condition indicates when to *enter* the loop, rather than when to *stop entering*.

As Chris mentions in his comment, it's mostly better to use `<=`, as you might increment `i` within the body and skip `loopEnd`.

Comment: @Downvoter: I admin `<=` will be more elegant in most cases, but is `!=` really wrong? Or what else is the reason?

Comment: I did not downvote, but technically no it is not wrong.  Although, if I was incremented inside the loop it poses risk for a never ending loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `<=` with `loopEnd` in your loop. Like;

```
for (int i = loopStart; i <= loopEnd; i++)
```